# Spring @JsonFormat set date with one day less

Tags: java, json, spring, date, jackson

I have a problem with Date and Jackson.
If in the DB the date is "11-06-2018", when I get the output value the result is "10-06-2018".

In the model file, I declare the field like this:

```
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy", locale = "pt-BR", timezone = "Brazil/East")
    @Column(name = "date")
    private Date date;
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: which timezone is set in DB?

Comment: @dehasiI I do not think that's the problem, in the database the date is correct, if I run in the log of the date just extracted is correct, it is the JsonFormat that makes it then wrong

Comment: my idea was that there are different timezones (locales) in DB and in your properties. that's why Jackson converts it.